# How to implement calendar in Python?

Tags: python, date, calendar

For example I give the date as:

```
2/12/2015
```

The result should be:

```
February/Thursday/2015
```

I tried to do with `if` but I'm not getting the result. It would be nice if you could tell me the long way (without using built in functions (like `datetime` and others) too much). I'm new to python and not much is taught in my school.

Comment: It would be good if you could tell us what exactly you're having trouble with. Just giving you code won't help you learn and those kind of questions are also off-topic here.

Comment: not much is taught in my school

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use datetime *too much*, simply parse the date and output it in whatever format you want

```
from datetime import datetime

d = "2/12/2015"

print(datetime.strptime(d,"%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%B/%A/%Y"))
February/Thursday/2015

A = Locale’s full weekday name.
B =  Locale’s full month name.
Y = Year with century as a decimal number.
```

All the format directives are [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html)

You could create a dict mapping but you will find datetime is  lot simpler.

Comment: what i meant was not to use built in functions.that is without built in functions

Comment: @Animeartistfromhell7, is this homework? Also not too much is very different from not at all

Comment: Now StackOverflow is supposed to do homework for lazy teenagers? I thought it was a good answer.

Comment: @Animeartistfromhell7, well let me reassure you trying to make your own date parser is not a trivial undertaking by anyones standards. You would be far better off familiarising yourself with the datetime library.